# iphone app icons - low & hi res

Tags: iphone, icons

how can i provide both, a high and low resolution version of my iphone app icon ? do i "need" to provide 2 versions, or takes apple care of downsampling my high resolution icon ?

thanks

Comment: just add "@2x" to the end of image names for the high res versions and the iphone will decide what to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's optional

Check this page:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2010/qa1686.html

Note that as a standard
Icon@2x.png (and all @2x prefixes) are for the retina display devices.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide 2 icons of different resolution.
How can you expect apple will take care of your application?

Comment: what i meant was if apple automatically resamples a highres icon to 57x57. i did not expect anything. thats why i asked. thanks for your answer anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You still need the low res icon for iOS versions before 4.0.

Comment: Also, regarding that Apple document Chen Harel mentions above. It contains a minor error. This document mentions a "Icon files" key shortcut for the plist editor, but in the plist editor in Xcode 3.2.4 it doesn't have this shortcut, instead you need to use the "CFBundleIconFiles" key.